# Current directory doesnt get added to sys.path when running VSCode nodebug

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When a file is run with "Start debugging" in VSCode the files directory gets added to sys.path. But when it is run with "Start without debugging" sys.path only has the empty string in the first position. What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference. Please open an issue at https://www.github.com/microsoft/vscode-python .

Comment: @BrettCannon Thank you. Will do.